# How Gas Springs or Gas Struts are pressurized with nitrogen gas and then sealed?

Tags: manufacturing-engineering

Prior to testing and probably painting, the last stage of manufacturing a gas spring or gas strut is **pressurizing with Nitrogen**. I was wondering how this step is done. I think it is filled with gas **from the rod side** and the rod seal works as **an one way path**, meaning, nitrogen gas is injected into the cylinder with certain amount of pressure, and then when the injection is stopped, the pressurized nitrogen in the cylinder **pushes the seal back** and seals the gas strut, but I’m not sure.

Answer (score 1):

See https://youtu.be/w0XYrs8_NFc?t=302 at 5:02. The whole gas spring is placed inside a pressure vessel, which is filled with gas at high pressure. As you suggest, the seal around the rod acts as a one-way valve, letting gas in, but not back out again.